# Convert the code into Array..... in Flex

Tags: php, apache-flex

```
$output = "<loginsuccess>";


while( $Row = mysql_fetch_object( $result ) )
{

$output .="<keyword>".$_POST['keyword']."</keyword><name>".$row['url']."</name><occur>".$row['occurrences']."</occur><queryTime>".(substr($end_time-$start_time,0,5))."</queryTime>";
}

$output .= "</loginsuccess>";
```

This is my PHP output, how can i convert the piece of code into Array in Flex. This is my output which i am reading in flex through event.result.loginsucess, but want this output as array there.

Thanks

Comment: i assume you mean to parse xml to array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the resultFormat property in HTTPService tag to "object" - see this: [Converting xml to objects using the flex httpservice mxml tag](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/19/converting-xml-to-objects-using-the-flex-httpservice-mxml-tag/)